# Oracle XML Schema Validation date pattern error

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

i am trying to validate an XML with an XSD. But it throws a strange error about the date format:

> [1]: LSX-00333: literal "2016-05-26T16:37:42.000000" is not valid with respect to the pattern

However this is what I have in my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root DataFeed="2016-04" 
      VersionXSD="2.0" 
      Currency="USD" 
      DataProcessDate="2016-05-26T16:37:42" 
      xmlns="http://www.millicom.com">
```

I have this in my XSD:

```
<xs:attribute name="DataProcessDate" 
              use="required" 
              type="DateTimeType"/>

<xs:simpleType name="DateTimeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:pattern value=".+(\-10:00|\-09:00|\-08:00|\-07:00|\-06:00|\-05:00|\-04:00|\+00:00|Z|-04:00)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And this is my code:

```
DECLARE
   v_schema_url   VARCHAR2 (200) := 'MyFact.xsd';
   v_blob         BLOB;
   v_clob         CLOB;
   v_xml          XMLTYPE;
   xml_file BFILE;
   xmlClob CLOB;

   src_offset number := 1 ;
   dest_offset number := 1 ;
   lang_ctx number := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
   warning integer;
   res integer;
BEGIN
   dbms_xmlschema.deleteschema(v_schema_url); 
   DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerschema (schemaurl   => v_schema_url,
                                  schemadoc   => bfilename ('DIR_XSD','MyFact.xsd'),
                                  local       => TRUE);
   xml_file := BFILENAME('DIR_XSD', 'Test.xml');
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlClob, true);
   DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(xml_file, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
   DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE(xmlClob, xml_file, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, src_offset,
                             dest_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_ctx, warning);

   v_xml := XMLType.createXML(xmldata=>xmlClob,schema=>v_schema_url);

   DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSEALL();
   DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlClob);

   v_xml.schemaValidate();

   IF v_xml.isschemavalid (v_schema_url) = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('valid');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('not valid');
   END IF;
END;
```

For some reason it adds the micro seconds and it fails the pattern check. How can I avoid this?
My desired behavior is a correct execution with an output of "valid"

Comment: Edited to include what you stated

Comment: Without the declaration of your `DateTimeType` it's hard to say what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting it, editted it in. Although the answer Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz gave me helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably doing somthing like this. 
I assumed you data type is declared like this.

```
  <xs:simpleType name="DataProcessDateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
       <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

And what's happening here.

- 1) `2016-05-26T16:37:42` string is converted to xs:dataTime and looking like 
  `2016-05-26T16:37:42.000000`.
- 2) Next xsd is traying match `2016-05-26T16:37:42.000000` to pattern `"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"` but  pattern hasn't trailing zeros. And LSX-00333 error is raised.

What you can do.

- (1- option) Include trailing zeros in pattern `"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}"`
- (2 - option) Remove  xs:pattern  from type;

  ```
   xsd clob := q'~<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="DataFeed"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="VersionXSD"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Currency"/>
            <xs:attribute type="DataProcessDateType" name="DataProcessDate"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="DataProcessDateType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
         <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:schema>~';
  begin 
     DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerschema (schemaurl   => 'test_xsd',
                                    schemadoc   => xmltype(xsd),
                                    local       => TRUE);
  end;
  ```

  -- exec dbms_XMLSCHEMA.deleteSchema(schemaurl   => 'test_xsd') ;
      declare 
          vxml xmltype := xmltype(q'~~');

  ```
  begin 
    vxml := vxml.createschemabasedxml('test_xsd');
    vxml.schemaValidate();
   IF vxml.isschemavalid ('test_xsd') = 1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('valid');
     ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('not valid');
     END IF;
  end;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't shown us your data type definition, my first instinct is that Oracle are interpreting the spec incorrectly. Personally I think that using patterns with non-string datatypes is highly questionable, but the spec is pretty clear (part 2, §4.1.4, validation rule Datatype Valid) that the pattern facet should be used to match the value as written in the source document (after whitespace normalization) called "a literal in the lexical space", and this is then converted to the value space, where other facets such as minInclusive and enumeration are assessed. I get the impression that Oracle have instead taken the lexical value, converted it to the value space, and are then testing the canonical lexical form of the value against the pattern. But that's not right either, because the canonical lexical form cannot contain trailing zeroes in the fractional seconds part (see 3.2.7.2).